# React native No permission needed for camera or photo library access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am working on an app where the user needs to load images from a photo library or camera, I am using the `react-native-image-picker` library for accessing the camera, however, I use it without react-native-permissions and it still works. I know it's not a good approach, I'm just curious how can I get into the user's photo library/camera without asking for permission, will the app get rejected when I will try to upload it on App Store or Google Play?

Comment: The library will handle when to ask permission. Check the library docs.

Comment: @RajendranNadar here is in the docs of image-picker: 
Permissions are no longer handled (nor do you need to). If you do list any permissions related to the image picker in your manifest/info.plist, it will be your responsibility to check & request permissions (do so recommend with react-native-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ask permissions for camera use, location use, photo library access you won't be able to upload your app to the App Store, and you'll have problem for Google Play too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29531943)

Comment: "will the app get rejected when I will try to upload it on App Store or Google Play?"